# How to properly use Nested relationships for serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to display whatever data I have in my CatPerm inside my Category API endpoint. My CatPerm data consists of 'cat', 'permission', and 'description' whereby they are category name, permission and description respectively

Whenever I try to takeaway:

```
    cat = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', read_only=True)
    permission = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', read_only=True)
```

from the CatPermSerializer, I'll have AttributeError:
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `cat` on serializer `CatPermSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Permission` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Permission' object has no attribute 'cat'.

**Current 'Category' API endpoint look:**

```
{
        "name": "Travel",
        "permission": [
            {
                "description": "Camera is used to take photos"
            }
        ]
    },
```

**This is my desired 'Category' API endpoint look:**

```
{
        "name": "Travel",
        "permission": [
            {
                "cat": "Travel",
                "permission": "Internet",
                "description": "This is a description inside CatPerm"

            }
        ]
    },
```

**models.py**

```
class CatPerm(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='permissions')
    permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission,
                                        related_name='category_permissions',
                                        through='CatPerm'
                                        )


class Permission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    platform = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES,
        default=BOTH,
    )
    classification = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=CLASSIFICATION_CHOICES,
        default=LOW,
    )
```

**serializer.py**

```
class CatPermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cat = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', read_only=True)
    permission = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CatPerm
        fields = ("cat", "permission", "description")


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permission = CatPermSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("name", "permission")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If would like to customize your response, you could override `to_representation()`.

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
       model = Category
       fields = ('name',)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        # Here you can do whatever you need, for instance add different fields to response
        data['permissions'] = []
        for perm in instance.permissions.all():
            data['permissions'].append({'name': perm.name})
        return data
```

Comment: I am getting the error "RelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships I am trying to achieve something similar in this link. But I cant seem to display the information I have in CatPerm

Comment: @Jerry I've just fixed the code. It was missing to call `.all()` on for.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jerry I'm glad to help you. Please, don't forget to mark answers as accept when your issue is solved. Thanks.